# Unable to mount CephFS on client - Rocky8.8

Tags: ceph, cephfs

When attempting to mount a Ceph file system the `mount` command times out:

```
mount error 110 = Connection timed out
```

dmesg shows the following:

```
ceph: device name is missing path (no : separator in splunk@$FSID.splunkfs=/)

libceph: mon0 (1)$IP:6789 socket closed (con state V1_BANNER)

ceph: No mds server is up or the cluster is laggy
```

The Ceph cluster appears healthy:

```
ceph -s
  cluster:
    id:     $ID
    health: HEALTH_OK
```

MDS' are available:

```
Filesystem 'splunkfs' (3)
fs_name splunkfs
epoch   25
flags   12 joinable allow_snaps allow_multimds_snaps
created 2023-11-14T21:48:12.816648+0000
modified    2023-11-14T21:48:19.975166+0000
tableserver 0
root    0
session_timeout 60
session_autoclose   300
max_file_size   1099511627776
required_client_features    {}
last_failure    0
last_failure_osd_epoch  13603
compat  compat={},rocompat={},incompat={1=base v0.20,2=client writeable ranges,3=default file layouts on dirs,4=dir inode in separate object,5=mds uses versioned encoding,6=dirfrag is stored in omap,7=mds uses inline data,8=no anchor table,9=file layout v2,10=snaprealm v2}
max_mds 1
in  0
up  {0=1760832}
failed  
damaged 
stopped 
data_pools  [23]
metadata_pool   22
inline_data disabled
balancer    
standby_count_wanted    1
[mds.splunkfs.$HOST.xwzvhf{0:1760832} state up:active seq 4 join_fscid=3 addr v2:$IP:6817/919813082 compat {c=[1],r=[1],i=[7ff]}]
```

Various `mount` commands have been attempted with both the user credentials and the admin credentials:

```
mount -v -t ceph splunk@.splunkfs=/ -o secret=$KEY
mount -t ceph splunk@.splunkfs=/ /mnt/splunk -o secretfile=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.splunk.key
mount -v -t ceph $HOST:6789:/ /mnt/splunk -o name=splunk,fs=splunkfs,secretfile=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.splunk.key
mount -v -t ceph splunk@$FSID.splunkfs=/ /mnt/splunk -o 'secretfile=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.splunk.key,mon_addr=$IP'
```

Each results in some variant of:

```
parsing options: rw,secretfile=/etc/ceph/ceph.client.splunk.key,mon_addr=$IP
mount.ceph: resolved to: "$IP"
mount.ceph: trying mount with new device syntax: splunk@$FSID.splunkfs=/
mount.ceph: options "name=splunk,key=splunk,mon_addr=$IP" will pass to kernel
mount.ceph: trying mount with old device syntax: $IP:/
mount.ceph: options "name=splunk,key=splunk,mds_namespace=splunkfs,fsid=$FSID" will pass to kernel
mount error 110 = Connection timed out
```

A successful mount was performed when using `ceph-fuse`.

Ceph version:

```
ceph --version
ceph version 17.2.5 (98318ae89f1a893a6ded3a640405cdbb33e08757) quincy (stable)
```

`ceph-common` is installed on all ceph nodes.

Comment: Can your client reach the monitors? It requires access to the ceph public network to connect to the monitors. Do you have a local ceph.conf with the mon addresses? Any security options enabled?

Comment: Yes, I am able to Telnet from the client to the host of the required ports. My local ceph conf has my mon hosts and was generated with: `ceph config generate-minimal-conf`

Where do I check the ceph security settings?

Comment: I didn't mean ceph security but things like selinux, apparmor etc.

Comment: This [tracker issue](https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/21220) sounds familiar. What kernel version does your client have? Is it one of the ceph nodes or is it a separate client?

Comment: Here is my kernel version: 4.18.0-477.27.1.el8_8.x86_64

Comment: Could you try with a newer kernel version (> 5.x)?